# What does flex-shrink attribute in a flexbox item do?

Tags: css

I don't understand what the  flex-shrink attribute in a flexbox item means.

Maybe you can give me a small example.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-shrink.asp

Answer (score 1):

It "determines how much the flex item will shrink relative to the rest of the flex items in the flex container when there isn't enough space on the row." See "[flex-shrink](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-shrink/)"

Answer (score 0):

`flex-shrink` - This defines the ability for a flex item to shrink if necessary.
See [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)